# How to suppress singlesignon using the latest facebook sdk 4.1.0

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

In android 3.x there was a way to suppress single sign on using SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO. What is the equivalent way of doing it in Facebook SDK 4.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

The class is called LoginBehavior in v4

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginBehavior/